# How can the current task discover the id of the task which created it (its parent)?

Tags: task-parallel-library

I have some information that I would like to dribble down to child tasks which execute plug-in code (and, as such, do not have access to the calling code).

For this to work, I am trying to find the parent task ID of the current child--since exceptions are propogated to the parent by the TPL, it would seem to have this data.

However, I see no methods on the Task object to get its parent.

Comment: Parent-child relation in TPL is internal mechanism, and you probably should not rely on that. You need to implement some `Ambient Context` pattern by yourself, so the plug-ins can get the datstheyy do need.

Comment: Hmm.  That is discouraging but good-to-know.   I have implemented a unit-of-work-per-task pattern as one might expect.  I was hoping that I could automatically (i.e. implicitly) associate subtasks with the unit-of-work of the parent task.
BTW, it is intriguing to me that WIndows supports thread-scoped data but no task-scoped data.  Hmm.

Comment: If you start them inside the parent task, they will be automatically attached